# Can't animate images with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I don't know if I am missing something obvieouse but, I thought you can animate images in jquery? Basically I want to achive something like that http://jsfiddle.net/Qm2FG/ but with price tags on this site http://nagomedia.blackflow.pl.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Like I wrote I am trying to animate price tags http://nagomedia.blackflow.pl. but with no luck...

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you just use the code that you linked to in your question but you need to select the proper elements in your HTML document:

```
$('.content').children('.main').children().hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ top : "-=0.45em" }, 150);            
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ top :"+=0.45em" }, 150);
});
```

When I post this code into my developer console on your website, your tags start animating when I hover over them.

Notice the use of `.stop()` which is useful when using the `-=` and `+=` modifiers.

**UPDATE**

You need to either put your JS at the end of your HTML document (my personal favorite) or put the code in a document.ready event handler. Your code is trying to bind to elements that don't yet exist, so no binding is taking place.

```
$(function () {
    $('.content').children('.main').children().hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ top : "-=0.45em" }, 150);            
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ top :"+=0.45em" }, 150);
    });
});
```

I like to put my JS code at the end of my HTML documents so they don't block the rendering of the page. CSS goes in the `<head>` so it is available to properly style the document and JS is placed at the bottom to run once the DOM has been setup.

Comment: @MichałKorzeniowski You need to either put your JS at the end of your HTML document (my personal favorite) or put the code in a `document.ready` event handler. Your code is trying to bind to elements that don't yet exist, so no binding is taking place. Check my answer for an update.

Comment: You're welcome. These were pretty simple issues, you may want to read the Getting Started jQuery Docs or simply browse the API Docs to see what and how to do things in jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery